# List comprehension with inequality

Tags: python, list, max, list-comprehension

Good day,
I am trying to get the maximum value from the list x but I am getting a

**TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'.*

Where am I going wrong with this line of code? I assumed that "i" would brake out each element of x and a comparison could be made over each element of the list x that would return the maximum value of the list. But obvious I am wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
maximum = 0
maxx = [i for i in x if i > maximum]
print(maxx)
```

[EDIT]

I guess what I am trying to do is take this function (below) which returns a value and put it into a list comprehension. Is it even possible?

```
def maximum(x):     
maxx = x[0]      
    for i in x:       
        if (i>maxx):           
            maxx = i    
    return maxx
maximum([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Answer (score 4):

maximum shouldn't be a list, it should simply be an integer.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
maximum = 0
maxx = [i for i in x if i > maximum]
print(maxx)
```

Comment: Okay I am following but the print statement is only returning the list x not the maximum value 6

Comment: @Henry then you're requirement is incorrect. The solution below is what you need.

Comment: I edited my initial question to hopefully provide more clarity of what I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the requirement here is to just to get the maximum number within a list?

In that case you can directly call the max operation on the list -

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6, 9, 12]
print(max(x))
```